# This is a number guessing Python code ,but it stops after entering the first guessing number. Can you tell me where is the fault?

Tags: python, random, numbers

```
import random
winning_number = random.randint(1,100)
guess = 1
number = int(input("guess a number between 1 and 100: "))
while not game_over:
  if number == winning_number:
    print(f"you win, and you guessed this number in {guess} times ")
    game_over = True
  else:
    if number < winning_number:
      print("too low")
      guess += 1
      number = int(input("guess again: "))
    else:
      print("too high")
      guess += 1
      number = int(input("guess again: "))
```

I want to continue the guessing number until it reach the right answer.

Comment: You haven't defined `fame_over` before trying to test its value. Just before the `while` line, put in `game_over = False`.

Comment: You should have received an error message that is telling you what the fault is.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize `game_over`

Other improvements

- `guess` should start at 0
- move `guess += 1` and `number = ...` outside of if/else to remove duplicated code

```
import random
winning_number = random.randint(1,100)
guess = 0
game_over=False
number = int(input("guess a number between 1 and 100: "))
while not game_over:
  if number == winning_number:
    print(f"you win, and you guessed this number in {guess} times ")
    game_over = True
  else:
    if number < winning_number:
      print("too low")
    else:
      print("too high")
    guess += 1
    number = int(input("guess again: "))
```