# What is wrong in thsi code of number guessing question?

Tags: python-3.x, numbers

```
winning_number = 43
guess = 1
num = int(input("enter a number between 1 and 100"))
while not game_over:
  if wining_number==num:
    print(f"you win , you guessed the number in {guess} times")
    game_over=True
  else:
    if num>winning_number:
      print("too high")
      guess += 1
      num=int(input("guess again :"))
    else:
      print("too low")
      guess += 1
      num=int(input("guess again :"))
```

## Number is not guessed properly, it stops after putting only one number, what should i do?

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74929631/this-is-a-number-guessing-python-code-but-it-stops-after-entering-the-first-gue

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, you missed one n in this line:

```
if wining_number==num:
```

It must be so:

```
if winning_number==num:
```

Plus, you have to set the "game_over" variable to False value before the while loop.

```
game_over = False
```